# SQL exercise, help needed

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL and really stumped with a particular question, i'd really appreciate if someone could take the time to help me out with this one.

Question: Show the 3 biggest countries (by their population) on the least populous continent (except for Antarctica).

```
SELECT name ,
       country.population ,
       continent ,
       SUM(country.population) OVER ( PARTITION BY continent ) continent_population
FROM   country
WHERE  continent != 'Antarctica';
```

I've got this query so far which get me a table with the corresponding population of each continent, but what am i missing to narrow that down to the continent with the least population. Thanks for the help

Database ER diagram is below

[Database ER diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNLgE.png)

Comment: What have you already tried ?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: SELECT
name, country.population, continent, SUM(country.population) OVER (PARTITION BY continent) continent_population
FROM
country
WHERE
continent != 'Antarctica'

Comment: I've gotten to the above query so far but i don't get how to filter out the continent with the least population

Comment: I don't see any query.  Before asking question, learn how to ask question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Stick that working SQL in a subquery and filter it.

Comment: Thing is im not sure how that subquery would look like. I want to narrow down by choosing continent population = min(continent population) but i obviously cant do that since continent population is a temporary column i created.

Comment: What dbms is this?

Comment: pgAmdin3 - PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just order your results and get the top 3.

```
SELECT 
       name ,
       country.population ,
       continent ,
       SUM(country.population) OVER ( PARTITION BY continent ) continent_population
FROM   country
WHERE  continent != 'Antarctica'
ORDER BY 
  continent_population ASC, 
  country.population DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: Oh yeah, this works, i've been trying to figure out how to put this in a subquery when all i had to do is order. i just added a LIMIT 3 at the end to show the top 3. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @hhkk It sounds like this solved your question, so you should mark it as the answer.